# On Android keyboard flashes when editing table JS Tablulator

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, tabulator

Tabulators [mainpage](http://tabulator.info/) example works on mobile just fine.
When trying to edit a column on Android phone the keyboard shows up and then almost immediately goes away leaving the box unselected.

Using Tabulator Version 4.2.1

I have copied source code given with no luck, any help would be grateful.

I'm using the [XAMMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) stack to locally host the website
Using Android version 9 with web browser chrome Version 72.0.3626.105

```
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
        responsiveLayout:"hide",  //hide columns that dont fit on the table
        columns:[                 //define the table columns
            {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input"},
            {title:"Task Progress", field:"progress", align:"left", formatter:"progress", editor:true},
            {title:"Gender", field:"gender", width:95, editor:"select", editorParams:{"Male":"male", "Female":"female"}},
            {title:"Color", field:"col", width:130, editor:"input"},
            {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", width:130, sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        ],
    });

    var tableData = [
        {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
    ]
    table.setData(tabledata);
```

Not sure why it is not working, don't know if it is a bug or something on my end.

Any advice would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a height on your table in order to use the virtual DOM. At the moment you are trying to use options like ***responsiveLayout*** that only work when the virtual DOM is enable, but with out a height it has no idea how big the scroll area should be.